Certificate for multiple DNS names: Besides Subject Alternative Name, anything else required for correct verification?
I have created a LetsEncrypt certificate that contains two domains, one.example.com and two.example.com (Note, I am aware of wildcard certificates but this question is multiple names in one certificate).
The certificate has one.example.com as CN and both one.example.com and two.example.com as X509v3 Subject Alternative Name attributes.
I use the certificate with nginx.
Conventionally, the client would just check if CN matches the DNS name and I expect that as long as one.example.com and two.example.com now point to the same nginx server, I could access them via both DNS names. But only one.example.com works.
I can reproduce this with openssl:
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername one.example.com -connect 192.168.151.97:443                                                          
Connecting to 192.168.151.97
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E5
verify return:1
depth=0 CN=one.example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN=one.example.com
   i:C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E5
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: ecdsa-with-SHA384
   v:NotBefore: Jul 17 05:27:55 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Oct 15 05:27:54 2024 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E5
   i:C=US, O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 384 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Mar 13 00:00:00 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Mar 12 23:59:59 2027 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=CN=one.example.com
issuer=C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=E5
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2434 bytes and written 410 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---


openssl s_client -showcerts -servername two.example.com -connect 192.168.151.97:443
Connecting to 192.168.151.97
CONNECTED(00000003)
402EB7DC01000000:error:0A000458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:907:SSL alert number 112
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 333 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

So you can see, one.example.com works but two.example.com does not work, even though it is listed as Subject Alternative Name.
Even when I explicitly specify -servername two.example.com, the situation does not change.
Why do browsers/openssl not successfully verify two.example.com?

Since you got no certificates at all in the second connection (and got TLS alert 112) it seems like you've not actually set NGINX up to know that it's both one.example.com and two.example.com; and NGINX is rejecting the connection early with "I don't know what this servername you're trying to connect to is".  So, check  your nginx configuration.

Oh I see. I think this is where I am going to. But I don't understand why nginx even cares? I have only worked with apache and SSL certs before and as long as I connected to port 443, SSL connection was opened and the client had to verify that the request DNS name matches DN.


402EB7DC01000000:error:0A000458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes
:tlsv1 unrecognized name:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:907:SSL alert number 112
---
no peer certificate available


According to these lines, openssl cannot verify the certificate because there is nothing to verify – the server did not send a certificate, instead it sent an "Unrecognized name" alert.
This usually means that the client requested a -servername which your Nginx configuration has no matching server{} block for.
Usually the matching of TLS Server Name Indication requests to server configurations is not done against the certificates themselves; instead it's done against manually configured names – in other words, TLS SNI is for selecting vhosts as much as it is for selecting certificates (and some servers enforce that), so when a client requests TLS SNI "two.example.com" the server does not just send any certificate it has that happens to match, but specifically the certificate that's configured in the corresponding vhost block.

I don't understand why nginx even cares? I have only worked with apache and SSL certs before and as long as I connected to port 443, SSL connection was opened and the client had to verify that the request DNS name matches DN.

Both are reasonable implementations of TLS SNI. If an HTTP client requested a vhost that the server didn't have configured, one HTTP server might return a default vhost while another would return a "403/404 no such vhost" error, often for security reasons (e.g. to prevent unwanted domains from pointing to it) – likewise, when the client explicitly requests a certificate for a name that's not configured as a vhost, the server may assume that it's not meant to be accessed through that domain.
(Apache has the same option as SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck.)
